# Tensorflow speed-up prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a problem regarding prediction performance. What I do is I repeatedly call `test_predictions` op in Python loop and put all its return values into the list. The code looks like this:

```
predictions = []
for _ in trange(args.num_batches):
    predictions.extend(sess.run(model.test_predictions))
```

When I look at performance statistics for more than 2/3 of time my GPU card is idle, probably because of continual switching between Python and TF code. I cannot make batch size bigger, because it won't fit in memory. Is there any better solution I can implement?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "switching between Python and TF code". If the GPU is idle a lot, that means your fetching of the data (images?) to run the predictions on takes a long time and the GPU has to wait a lot for the data to arrive.

Try implementing pre-fetching.

Alternatively, if you have enough memory, just read all images in at once and feed your network that way.